# ActiveScaffold: How do I set the default value for a drop down list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activescaffold

So I have this create form to create schedules where there is a bunch of fields and one of them is seasons. And seasons table has a field called 'is_current' which if set to 1 tells us that it is the current season. When the create form is display , I want the current season to be selected by default in the seasons drop down. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your answers, but my question is how to achieve this in ActiveScaffold. ActiveScaffold genereates views dynamically. Please refrain from general rails answers. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just change it on the view you have the drop down? Or you're talking about many views?

Comment: The views are dynamically generated. There are no .rhtml or .erb files. ActiveScaffold requires configuration in controller for the generated views.

Comment: Right... I'm sorry for the misunderstood. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be something like

```
#controller
@seasons = Season.all    
@current_season = seasons.detect{ |s| s.is_current==true }

#view    
select('schedule', 'season_id', @seasons.collect{ |s| [s.name, s.id] },
       :selected => @current_season)
```

**Edit**

Sorry for the misunderstanding... I would try something like the following:

Create a `named_scope` on `Season` model

```
named_scope :current, :conditions => "is_current = true"
```

and try to set up this option

```
config.columns[:seasons].options = {:selected => Season.current}
```

I don't know if it works. It's just a shot.

Comment: You shouldn't make model calls in views.

Comment: I did't actually said to do the call in the view, but I'll specify

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:selected` attribute in the `select` form method, though this will expect the value of the `option` tag. Let's make a simple dropdown that has the ID of the season as the option value, the name of the season as what the user sees and a specific record selected by default, like this:

```
<option value="123" selected="selected">Name of season</option>
<option value="234">Another season</option>
```

In this case, the `:selected` attribute will expect `123`, so that it knows to make it the default value.

You can accomplish that with the following code:

Controller:

```
@seasons        = Season.all
@current_season = @seasons.detect{|s| s.is_current == 1}.id
```

View (in a form_for statement):

```
<%= f.select :season_id, @seasons.collect {|s| [s.name, s.id]}, :selected => @current_season %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You have to add a piece of code in the appropriate helper file, in my case the schedules_helper.rb.

```
def seasons_list
  s = Season.find(:all, :order => 'is_current DESC').map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}
end
```

This will make sure the current season is always the first option of the drop down and hence by default is selected.

Thanks all, for your answers.